# Insert custom field input data from user into $wpdb in wordpress without using plugin?

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

I have a website in word press i have added the following HTML custom field on the front page in WordPress ,Here i am taking input data from user and i have to insert that input data into my WordPress database without using any plugin.The problem is that i am not able to insert data in data base table.All the code(HTML+php) is in front-page.php file.
Here is my HTML code

```
 <form method="post" action="">

 <div style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #bbb; padding:10px;">
    <div>
        <label for="name">name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="message">message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" style="width:250px; height:100px"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="signup" value="signup" />
</div>
</form>
```

Here is my WordPress php code

```
 <?php wp_reset_query();
    $wpdb->insert(
    $tbl_custom,
    array(


    "name" => $name,
"email" => $email,
"mesage" => $massege,
        
    )
    );
  $Offerid=$wpdb->insert_id;
   //var_dump( $wpdb->last_query );
    ?>
```

Below is table structure

### Table structure for table `custom`

```
CREATE TABLE `custom` (
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Below is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: I am not able to insert data in custom table. @wordpresser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer bellow is example insert custom field data to WordPress data base.

```
<?php

If($_POST['Submit']) {
// run validation if you're not doing it in js
global $wpdb;

$coursename=$_POST['coursename'];
$coursename1=$_POST['coursevalue'];
$coursecategory=$_POST['coursecategory'];

if($wpdb->insert(
        'custom',
        array(
                'name' => $coursename,
                'email' => $coursename1,
                'message' =>$coursecategory
            )
) == false) wp_die('Database Insertion failed'); else echo 'Database insertion successful<p />';

?>
<a href="" onClick="return false;" id="addform">Add Another Course.</a>
<?php
}
else // else we didn't submit the form, so display the form
{
?><form action="" method="post" id="addcourse">

<label id="coursename">Course Name:<input type="text" name="coursename" size="30" /></label>
<label id="coursevalue">Points Value:<input type="text" name="coursevalue" size="10"  /></label>

<label id="coursecategory">Course Category:<select name="coursecategory" size="1">
        <option selected>Product Knowledge</option>
        <option>Demonstrate Effectively</option>
        <option>Perfect Your Pitch</option>
        <option>Business Integration and Technical Training</option>
    </select></label>

<p> </p>
<p> </p>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="addcoursesubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<a href="" onClick="return false;" id="addform">Add Another Course.</a>
<?php
} // end else no post['submit']
{
?>
```